# Raven Migration issue with NServiceBus 7x (Method not found)

Tags: migration, ravendb

I tried looking for some descriptive answer but didn’t found one.
**What I did**
Upgraded NserviceBus from 5x to 7x
This implicitly upgraded nugets:

- NserviceBus.RavenDb (3x to 5x)
- RavenDb.Client (3.0 to 3.5.5)
- Raven.Abstractions (3.5.5)
- RavenDb client build is 35247. So cannot upgrade RavenDbClient nuget to higher version.

**Error**:
RunTime error. "**System.MissingMethodException**: Method not found: *Raven.Abstractions.Data.BatchResult*"
The service handling messages is also having some already processed RavenMigrations (inheriting from Migration). I tried to test them (by changing id and find out that Migrations crash with some error as shown in image underneath:
[image]

Scratching my head on this error for a while now. Any hints what could be wrong?

*Note: This error was not happining with RavenDb.Client nuget 3.0*